# How to format custom fields when editing an attachment?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field

I'm adding some custom fields to attachments, doing roughly this in a plugin (based on [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-attachments--wp-31100)):

```
function myplugin_add_attachment_fields( $form_fields, $post ) {

    $fields = array(
        'myplugin_credit' => array(
            'label'         => 'Credit',
            'input'         => 'text',
            'application'   => 'image',
            'exclusions'    => array('audio', 'video'), 
            'helps'         => "e.g. 'Bob Ferris'"
        )
        // More fields here.
    );

    foreach($fields as $name => $field_data) {
        if ( preg_match( "/" . $field_data['application'] . "/", $post->post_mime_type) && ! in_array( $post->post_mime_type, $field_data['exclusions'] ) ) {

            $field_data['value'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_' . $name, true );

            $form_fields[$name] = $field_data;
        }
    }

    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'myplugin_add_attachment_fields', 11, 2 );
```

This all works fine but the fields look like this when editing a Media item:

[image]

Two questions:

1. How can I easily make the labels ("Credit", "Publisher") line up vertically with the input field itself?
2. How can I make the input field as wide as the standard fields on the page?

I do know how to use CSS to make this work, but I don't know how to do this in a nice WordPress way from within my plugin.

**UPDATE:** In case it helps anyone, after using socki03's answer to add my own CSS file, I put this in it to fix the layout issue:

```
.compat-attachment-fields th.label {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.compat-attachment-fields,
.compat-attachment-fields input.text {
    width: 100%;
}

.compat-attachment-fields p.help {
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to include and enqueue a new CSS file for your plugin on the admin side using [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts). And since you may want to load this on every page, I'd follow the first example on the Codex (pasted here):

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

But instead of the `get_template_directory` function, you'll want to use the [`plugin_dir_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) function, I believe.

```
function load_custom_wp_admin_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' );
```

To answer your two questions, it looks like the labels are vertically aligned in a table format.  So, if that's the case, you'll need to vertically align the content to the top, and then change the width of the table, and all subsequent inputs to 100% or something like that.  Without inspection, I'm just guessing at the image...

Comment: That's it, thanks so much! One thing - you need to add `__FILE__` to that method call: `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'll edit my answer.